# Building a compact and bright 940 nm IR light source?

Tags: led, integrated-circuit, infrared

I'm working on a small personal Airsoft related project and have been looking at ways I can make a bright 940 nm light source.
Hoping to be able to illuminate 20 m or greater area so that I can see clearly in the dark with use of an Raspberry Pi NoIR Camera v2, showing similar results as a night vision camera or night vision rifle scope.

I've seen there are several illumination options such as LED, Bulb and Chip.
 
- What type of Infrared light source from the above would be the best choice for a bright, long range, compact and low power solution?
 
- What makes Infrared lights brighter / duller?
 
- are there other sources of Infrared light sources I haven't stated above that could be effective for the project?

- Are there any dangers using 940 nm light sources?

Comment: You forgot to actually ask a clear question! I removed the "Any help would be welcome", because it's pretty obvious it a) is and b) that you're a polite person, anyways, and c) it distracted from the fact that you probably have a clear question, but didn't ask it (it's kind of there, I'm just not sure enough to ask it myself).

Comment: My Apologies Marcus, I was just trying to be polite. :)
Also sorry for the way I've worded my question, I'll try add in clearer detail to the question.

Comment: Why specifically 940nM?  Also, why not just buy an IR flashlight?

Comment: Yeah, a 940nm laser is really dangerous. Especially the higher power ones. You can't see anything but a dark spot move across your vision, except the spot stays there because it burned a hole in your retina.

Comment: Hey @wbeaty
The reason I'm going to be building a 940Nm light instead of buying a flashlight is to fit a custom built housing.

Comment: @laptop2d isn't there a difference between an IR laser and an IR light source? I thought the Laser was run of a diode instead of a LED, or are all IR light sources at 940Nm still dangerous for the human eye?

Comment: Its not the frequency, its the source and the intensity. Only when you go to higher frequencies do things get dangerous (past blue) because of ionizing radiation. Infrared is not inherently dangerous. But you didn't specify the source. https://www.google.com/search?q=ir+light+source+safety&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh3bvk5uXRAhXosFQKHTnzDxcQvwUIGigA

Comment: @TitanStudios buy cheap IR flashlight that does what you want, saw it apart, fit custom housing.  LEDs are not lasers, yet lasers are LEDs!    Yes, laser light above 10milliwatts is dangerous unless spread into a wide beam, where 10mW total can never enter an eye.   Several-watts IR laser modules are cheap and common, IF NOT 940nM!!!  try 808nM

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question whether you want a small beam or a wide light source.

When I worked in the lasergaming industry, most often a relatively low power LED was used in combination with a lens that focused the beam. The small beam uses the power very efficient to get a long range (easily 20m).

Alternatively if you would like a wider beam, I have good experience with the small chip LEDs of 1-3W, as shown below.

[image]

These LEDs have a very wide beam (120 degrees or so), but can still send data to a range of 10m when not focussed.

**Safety**
Lasers are very focussed and I would therefore advise not to use it in an application where it can hit people. Normal IR Leds are safe for the eye as long as you don't focus them too much.
Think of the sun, if you focus the light with a lens it can burn things. The same is true for IR, except that you can not see the light.

**Edit: Nightvision**
For use in night vision, the most important part is finding a very sensitive camera. The 1-3W leds shown above are capable of lighting ar room well enough to view it with a (crappy) mobile phone camera wihtout IR filter. 
However, for night vision you would probably want a more focussed beam (that only lights the field of view of the camera). In that case you can either use lenses or buy an IR torch, which has a similar LED but is focussed by a reflector (e.g. [IR torch](http://www.ebay.com/itm/381393855241)).

[image]

Comment: Sorry by the way I worded my questions and thank you for sharing the above.
 | 
I've been looking for a way to light up an area of 20 meters + so that an IR camera can clearly see whats going on in the dark.
"Think of the night vision ready CCTV camera's" are the 1W-3W LED capable of achieving this visibility requirement or is the 10m restricted to data transmission?
 |
I'm working on a constructing a compact night vision scope.
I've opt in for 940nm over 850nm to hide the red tint of light the 850nm displays, trying to keep things low profile in the airsoft games.

Comment: I added some info about the LEDs for night vision. I think it is feasible but highly depends on the camera.

Comment: Hey @Douwe66

The Raspberry Pi NoIR Camera Module Version 2 is what I have currently..

Comment: Maybe just try out some LEDs. You can for example see how well a remote control lights the field of view of your camera, when you hold down a button.